# How to type a dash (— or –) instead of a hyphen(-) in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, markdown, symbols

On Mac and some other systems,  typing two hyphens quickly "--", would be automatically converted to an em dash "—" or an en dash "–" depending on the setting. But Stack Exchange fields are different, and this feature does not work.

Therefore, how to type dashes in Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The HTML entities `&ndash;` and `&mdash;` work on all systems: in the rendered post, they will be shown as – resp. —.

On a Mac (and on iOS devices connected to a physical keyboard), you can use <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for an en-dash and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for an em-dash. (<kbd>⌥</kbd> is the Option or Alt key).

On iOS, you can hold the <kbd>-</kbd> button and a sub-menu will appear which allows you to choose between different types of dashes.

On Windows, if you have a numeric keypad, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0150 resp. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0151.

Comment: Oh cool! I forgot about HTML entities... And the Mac shortcut seem to be more handy and as helpful as well!! Thanks!

Comment: @jackxujh thank you for spotting the mistake. I always mix them up; because the *m* precedes the *n* in the alphabet, my mind thinks the *m* must correspond to the shorter dash.

Comment: You are welcome! I got that too! I found it is easier to distinguish them by their widths – an em-dash has the width of an "m", which is wider than an en-dash, who has the width of an "n". Wish it help!

Comment: Why can't I get an &mdash; here?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed HTML entities don't work in comments.

Comment: @Glorifindel Then is there any way to get an em-dash in comments, apart from copying and pasting?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed No, not really.

Comment: @Glorfindel can't you use the other methods described in your answer (i.e. Windows and Mac key combinations)? Since they don't use html-encoded strings and instead use the actual unicode character **edit:** — it works for Mac.

Answer (score 6):

On Chrome OS and some Linux distros, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then type:

- `2013` for an en-dash, or
- `2014` for an em-dash

(You can also type the hex code of any other Unicode character to enter it, too)

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, if you set up a keyboard layout that includes a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key (e.g., there is an option to map it to the useless Windows menu key on standard PC keyboards), you can type an en-dash with <kbd>Compose</kbd>+`--.` and an em-dash with <kbd>Compose</kbd>+`---`.

Comment: ̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣Well, for me, `AltGr`+`Shift`+`-` produces U+0323 Combining Dot Below. It would seem that `AltGr` shortcuts heavily depend on the keyboard layout in use.

Comment: Indeed, that is depending on the layout. And setting `AltGr` as the `Compose` key, the above answer works with English US layout, but it doesn't work with the layout in which `AltGr`+`Shift`+`-`  does work (one called Romanian Standard).

Answer (score 2):

The system doesn't have a way to do this. People achieve it by having their own shortcuts or by copying and pasting them.

Shift plus dash becomes underscore because that's how QWERTY keyboards are set up. That's not a Stack Exchange customization.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of the shortcut for underlines!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Glorfindel has mentioned about the use of

> On a Mac (and on iOS devices connected to a physical keyboard), you
> can use <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for an en-dash and <kbd>⇧
> Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for an em-dash.
> (<kbd>⌥</kbd> is the Option or Alt key).
>
> On Windows, if you have a numeric keypad, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
> 0150 resp. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0151.

There's a great extension [ChromeDash](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromedash/bbpiealmmbiefhppikadopbljoppcnoa/related) that solves this problem gracefully. I find this to be a much better solution than using the cumbersome commands. But note that this only works on Google Chrome.

Simple Instructions of use-case

> Simply enter two dashes (hyphens) for an en–dash, and three for an em–dash! This can be changed, as can all other aliases you make!

This works nearly anywhere, in google, hangouts, messenger, facebook, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I know my question was originally about typing dash in SE, but @Glorindel's answer is more general and is supported by OS, meaning it could be used wherever text is inputed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I left this in the hope that it may help someone just searching around

Comment: thank you for the addition, I am sure some readers will find it useful!